# I need that it redirects multiple sites to the same error page

Tags: tomcat

I have an application running on Tomcat that is working fine.
When I call http://example.com:18080/app it works fine.
Now I create simple error page to redirect when there is an error:

```
<html>
<head> 
<title>Error Page</title>
</head>
<body> That's an error! </body>
</html>
```

And I added it on my web.xml

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

When I call http://example.com:18080/app/blabla it goes to my error page, but when I call http://example.com:18080/blabla or just http://example.com:18080 I need that it redirects to the same error page.

Does anybody have any idea how to do it?

Thanks

Fabio

Answer (score 1):

The Servlet Specification requires for the error pages to be internal to the web application (cf. [error pages](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/jakarta-servlet-spec-5.0.html#error-pages)). So you can either:

- add the same error pages to **all** applications,
- use container specific mechanisms instead of error pages.

In Tomcat the `ErrorReportValve` (cf. [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/valve.html#Error_Report_Valve)) is responsible for printing the error messages which are **not** customized by the application. If your error message is a simple HTML (let's say "404.html") you can save it in an arbitrary location (let's say `$CATALINA_BASE/errors`) and add an explicit `ErrorReportValve` to `server.xml`:

```xml
<Host>
  ...
  <Valve
    className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve"
    showServerInfo="false"
    errorCode.404="errors/404.html"/>
</Host>
```

However, if you want to use a JSP or servlet to format the error page, you need to:

1. Add the `<error-page>` element to all applications by adding the following to `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml`:

```xml
<error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/WEB-INF/errors/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

2. Mount the `$CATALINA_BASE/errors` folder under `WEB-INF/errors` in all applications. This can by done by adding the following to the `<Context>` element in the `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml`:

```xml
<Context>
  ...
  <Resources
    className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot">
    <PostResources
      className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet"
      base="${catalina.base}/errors"
      webAppMount="/WEB-INF/errors"/>
  </Resources>
</Context>
```