# Where is Tomcat's default error page located?

Tags: java, tomcat

Where are Tomcat's default error pages located or how can I customize them? I wish to beautify and change the look and feel of current error pages of Tomcat.

Comment: makes very little sense. you want to "beautify" what isn't there? you can beautify the default error page for your application, though.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to do it just for my application. I want to do it at Tomcat's level. By  beautify I meant change colour theme from gray to  blue / yellow like. Add Logo. Link to some other page and all.

Comment: yes, I understand that. I'm merely pointing out it makes no sense at all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default error pages are created by Java code:

- the HTML content is created by the `ErrorReportValve`: see [source code](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/09193e0514ac449df454184941bba492d9b20a85/java/org/apache/catalina/valves/ErrorReportValve.java#L240),
- the localized messages are in the `LocalStrings_<locale>.properties` files of the same package: see the [English version](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/09193e0514ac449df454184941bba492d9b20a85/java/org/apache/catalina/valves/LocalStrings.properties#L53).

If you want to replace them with static content, you need to:

- create a static HTML file, e.g. `$CATALINA_BASE/errors/404.html`,
- configure the `ErrorReportValve` accordingly:

  ```xml
  <Host>
      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve"
             errorCode.404="errors/404.html" />
  </Host>
  ```

External resources in error pages may cause problem: you must check that no security constraints are defined on those resources.

**Edit:** This of course works if the web applications don't define any error pages. If a custom error page exists in the application it has priority over the error pages defined in the `ErrorReportValve`.

#### Also see:

- [ErrorReportValve documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/valve.html#Error_Report_Valve)
- [I need that it redirects multiple sites to the same error page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68035289/11748454)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know the first and second point. third and fourth point I knew.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68051025/11748454) if you want to use the same JSP error page in all contexts.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz thanx for the answer. Please note that attribute is named `errorCode.404`, not `error.404`, as mentioned in https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/valve.html#Error_Report_Valve/Attributes