# How to access http status code in custom error Page in tomcat

Tags: jsp, custom-error-pages

I am using tomcat 8 and developing a generic custom error page in which i need to show custom error message based status code.if its 400 then need to display "message1" and if its 404 then "message2" in custom errorcode.jsp page.

I need to show custom message in errorcode.jsp based on status code.

Comment: Tomcat already has a default error page. Do you know where it's located? Ok, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68570741/573032) for details.